# How do you fetch data using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm fairly new to PDO in PHP and I'm trying to make a simple log-in form. I need to be able to fetch the data and can't seem to make that work with fetchColumn(), which I need to check if the user and password match.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM administrator
          WHERE user = :user
          AND pass = :pass";

$res = $db->prepare($query);

$params = array("user" => $username, "pass" => $password);
$res->execute($params);
$num_rows = $res->fetchColumn(1);

if ($num_rows) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $num_rows['user'];
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Failure";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
    <p>Hello, <?= $_SESSION['user']; ?>! This is admin content.</p>
    <a href=".?p=logout">Logout</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

When using this code, using the username `adminuser`, the output is:

```
"Hello, a! This is admin content."
```

when it should be:

```
"Hello, adminuser! This is admin content."
```

So, how does one fetch the data when the fetchColumn() function has already been executed?

Comment: `$num_rows` is a string containing the first column from your result, in this case `'adminuser'`. `$num_rows['user']` is trying to access a character from that string, where the string `'user'` is the index. Since indexing requires an integer, `'user'` gets coerced to `0`, and you end up retrieving the first character in the string: `adminuser][0]` -> `'a'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what fetchColumn does. It will simply return a single value.

You have two options:

1. Change `$num_rows['user']` to just `$num_rows` (strange naming convention there by the way). Here I'm assuming that you are actually targeting the correct column. See note below about using `*`

or

2. Use `$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead of fetchColumn, which will return an associative array containing all values in the row (which you can then continue to access with `$num_rows['user']`

If you go for option 1, I strongly recommend that you define which columns should be returned in your SELECT statement. Using `fetchColumn` with `SELECT * FROM` is very fragile, because the order of columns may change if new fields are added. To be honest, it's rare that you should use `*` anyway, so I'd probably specify the columns in any case.